# Finding the matrix $AB$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

We are told that A is a $m \times n$ matrix and B is a $n \times p$ matrix.

We are also given $C(B)$ is a subspace of the nullspace of A. We want to find the the matrix AB.

My first thought: How the hell do I approach problems like this...?

My attempt:
So we know that $Bx \in N(A)$, where $x$ is a $p \times 1$ vector. Let $Bx = y$

Continuing $Ay = 0$ since $y = Bx$ must be in the nullspace of $Ay$
$$Ay = 0 = ABx = 0$$

We had let $x$ be any vector as long as it was a $p \times 1$ vector, so in order for this equality to be true then AB must be the matrix of all zeroes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is indeed the matrix of all zeros.

Since $C(B)$ is a subspace of the nullspace of $A$, let $b_i$ be the $i$-th column of $B$. We have $Ab_i=0$.  Hence we have $AB=0$.